Why is Stellar SDK throwing [Object object] not a memo when memo is added when building transaction?
I'm trying to add a memo when generating a wallet on the Stellar network but the SDK keeps throwing this XDR write error.
Error stack trace:
TypeError: XDR Write Error: [object Object] is not a Memo
    at Function.write (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/union.js:85:1)
    at Function.write (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/struct.js:31:1)
    at Function.write (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/union.js:88:1)
    at Function.write (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/struct.js:31:1)
    at Function.toXDR (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/xdr-type.js:57:1)
    at ChildStruct.toXDR (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/js-xdr/src/xdr-type.js:12:1)
    at Transaction.signatureBase (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/stellar-base/lib/transaction.js:293:1)
    at Transaction.hash (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/stellar-base/lib/transaction_base.js:224:1)
    at Transaction.sign (webpack://WalletSDK/node_modules/@stellar/stellar-base/lib/transaction_base.js:88:1)
    at SigningKeypair.__webpack_modules__../src/walletSdk/Horizon/Account.ts.exports.SigningKeypair.SigningKeypair.sign (webpack://WalletSDK/src/walletSdk/Horizon/Account.ts:64:1)

Code:
    const createTxn = txBuilder
      .createAccount(createdAccountKeyPair)
      .setMemo(new Memo(MemoText, 'test-memo'))
      .build();

    const signed = sponsorSigningKeyPair.sign(createTxn);

These are the imports
import { Memo, xdr, MemoText } from '@stellar/stellar-sdk';
import {
  StellarConfiguration,
  Wallet,
  Keypair,
  AccountKeypair,
  IssuedAssetId,
  PublicKeypair,
  SigningKeypair,
  NativeAssetId,
} from '@stellar/typescript-wallet-sdk';

Versions:
    "@stellar/stellar-sdk": "^12.1.0",
    "@stellar/typescript-wallet-sdk": "^1.7.0",

This is my input:
    const createTxn = txBuilder
      .createAccount(createdAccountKeyPair)
      .setMemo(new Memo(MemoText, 'test-memo'))
      .build();

    const signed = sponsorSigningKeyPair.sign(createTxn);


It should be done like this:
setMemo(new Memo("text", "Memo string"))

You are using MemoText as the first parameter, which is wrong, it should be a string according to the docs.
When the error message is constructed, it seems to do MemoText.toString() which causes [Object object] to be printed.

Thanks @peter, i've tried this but it still returns same error.
